# Careers 2nd page bug - repeated header

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, pagination, ssl

When I clicked to the second page of https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=, the header was repeated. The footer is also repeated.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of bug]

Comment: Screenshot would've helped a lot..

Comment: Not just header.. See footer also.. Major design flaw...!

Comment: I can't reproduce in Firefox 26 on Windows 7. What OS/browser are you using?

Comment: I got the screenshot with Ubuntu(12.04)/Firefox(18.0.2)

Comment: Side note: anyone else having problems clicking the pagination buttons at the bottom? When I hover over page 2, the link looks correct but when I click it the page doesn't change.

Comment: Yup, reproduced with Chrome latest version. Super weird!

Comment: page change is not working.

Comment: See this answer by Nick: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216037/152859

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get an uncaught Security Error in Chrome (looking in the Developer Tools)

```
Uncaught SecurityError: A history state object with URL 'http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&pg=2' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://careers.stackoverflow.com'. jobs.min.js?v=8525c7a8307d:1
(anonymous function) jobs.min.js?v=8525c7a8307d:1
c jquery.js:3048
p.fireWith jquery.js:3160
k jquery.js:8235
r jquery.js:8778
```

Firefox blocks the content

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&pg=2&_=1389866004471"[Learn More]
```

Careers is being served by **https** but the pager uses the **http** which results in the above behavior and errors.

I´m not sure if https is fully supported yet, but when you access Careers using [http](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=) it works as expected.

Comment: Well, https is not yet fully supported so guess that bug isn't going to be fixed soon.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You never know. I'll create abug report may be fixed in a day or two.

Comment: @Juice cheers, Nick told "don't use https until it's fully supported" so just assumed it also applies to Careers. Isn't this very question a bug report though? Why create new one?

Comment: @ShadowWizard This is a bug report from you guys to us in general. I usually take these bugs reports, create a FogBugz ticket, and assign it to whichever dev is on bug duty.

Comment: @Juice cool, those are juicy details on your internal work as a dev! (pun intended ;)) Hmm... does it mean you're the Careers dev team leader?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ha! Absolutely not. I'm a terrible programmer. Ever seen this?, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAY27NU1Jog That's pretty much my job. I do customer support, sales support, and "work with" the devs; Help with new ideas, input on new features features, bug hunting, etc. This is just for Careers 2.0. I have zero to do with SO or SE sites.

Basically the Careers devs take turns being on bug duty. It's the only time I have any direct say over what they do, and even then they can tell me to shove off depending on the bug. I.E. if a bug is by design or too much work for too little gain.

Comment: @Juice OK, think I understand what you mean - well, you can ask for promotion when the time comes. I'm sure you can learn your way into programming - assuming you want it. :)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the diagnosis re SSL, that's exactly right. Our pagination links were hard-coded to http, which is obvs wrong. Try it again?

Comment: It works now. Think the question can be tagged as ´status-completed´