# Generated code does not respect correct protocol (eg. HTTPS)

Tags: bug, security, ssl

Browsing StackOverflow, I've found out, that not all resources are loaded over HTTPS (if using that protocol)

Looking into code, I've found out, it's related to Imgur addresses:

> view-source:https://stackoverflow.com/

```
<div class="question-summary narrow" id="question-summary-22183912" >
    <div onclick="window.location.href='/questions/22183912/onupgrade-android-sqlite-database-from-assets-folder'" class="cp">
        <div class="votes">
            <div class="mini-counts">0</div>
            <div>votes</div>
        </div>
        <div class="status unanswered">
            <div class="mini-counts">0</div>
            <div>answers</div>
        </div>
        <div class="views">
            <div class="mini-counts">7</div>
            <div>views</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="summary">

                    <h3><a href="/questions/22183912/onupgrade-android-sqlite-database-from-assets-folder" class="question-hyperlink" title="I currently have a database that I am using within my Assets folder. I am having issues upgrading it though. Whenever I up the DATABASE_VERSION number it will only update certain times. And when it ...">OnUpgrade Android SQLite Database from Assets Folder</a></h3>
        <div class="tags t-android t-database t-sqlite t-assets">
<!-- HERE -->       <a href="/questions/tagged/android" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;android&#39;" rel="tag"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png" height="16" width="18" alt="" class="sponsor-tag-img">android</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/database" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;database&#39;" rel="tag">database</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/sqlite" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;sqlite&#39;" rel="tag">sqlite</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/assets" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;assets&#39;" rel="tag">assets</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="started">
            <a href="/questions/22183912/onupgrade-android-sqlite-database-from-assets-folder" class="started-link"><span title="2014-03-04 21:53:25Z" class="relativetime">55m ago</span></a>
            <a href="/users/2607802/lukeg224">LukeG224</a> <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score " dir="ltr">10</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also related links, are not using the same protocol:

eg. Hot Network Questions

```
<div id="hot-network-questions" class="module">
    <h4>
        <a href="//stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot" 
           class="js-gps-track" 
           data-gps-track="posts_hot_network.click({ item_type:1, location:8 })">
            Hot Network Questions
        </a>
    </h4>
    <ul>
            <li >
                <div class="favicon favicon-photo" title="Photography Stack Exchange"></div><a href="http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48370/is-it-better-to-have-light-come-from-the-left-side" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site.switch({ item_type:8, target_site:61 }); posts_hot_network.click({ item_type:2, location:8 })">
                    Is it better to have light come from the left side?
                </a>

            </li>
```

or main `noscript`

```
<div id="noscript-warning">Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled<img src="http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif" alt="" class="dno"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is not only about imgur links, there should be consistency in protocol handling in all view fragments, thanks

Comment: The Hot Network Questions part is basically [All internal links on Stack Exchange sites should be protocol-relative](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223725/all-internal-links-on-stack-exchange-sites-should-be-protocol-relative). Haven't noticed that `pixel.quantserve.com` thing before, though.