# The linked content on chat servers isn't protocol relative

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, hyperlinks, ssl

The page at https://chat.stackexchange.com/ has all the stylesheets and scripts hard bound to use `http`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/css/chat.stackexchange.com.css?v=267360bbdcd6">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/favicon.ico?v=c3">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c3">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/js/master.js?v=0a552f322230"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/Js/third-party/jquery.autocomplete.css?v=7144f55258cb"/>
---
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/skins/topbar/topbar.css"/>
```

The `href` attributes should be protocol relative to user's preference. This can be considered a sub-request of [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223725/212576) ([All internal links on Stack Exchange sites should be protocol-relative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223725/212576))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that https is currently not officially supported (and we know about the certificate error); but - thanks for calling this to our attention. This should now work correctly. Note that if people link to external http images, they will *remain* as http images - we do not currently make all images etc **inside chats** protocol-relative.