# SE dropdown menu no longer works; review posts are empty

Tags: support

1. Starting this morning, with Google Chrome and IE11 at least, the StackExchange dropdown menu no longer works, except on the SE meta page. Instead, clicking "StackExchange" just goes to the SE front page.
2. Clicking to review a review queue (e.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts) shows only an empty question.
3. Also, adding a comment just stopped working. I added some this morning, even after noticing problems #1 and #2, but now I can not add a comment, e.g., here: [Search/replace-like feature for swapping text](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27135/search-replace-like-feature-for-swapping-text). The "Add comment" is not greyed-out, but when I click it the page just blinks - I get no text-edit box in which to enter the comment.

Google chrome automatically updated to 53.0.2785.116m, but I chose to revert to the previous style instead of the "Material" style (because the address-bar text was too small): top-chrome-md. Dunno whether this is related. I don't think so, because I didn't notice these problems yesterday, after the new Chrome version etc. I have tried closing the browser and clearing the cache, but that didn't help.

It's apparently not a Chrome problem. I see the same thing with IE11 - all the same symptoms: #1, #2, #3.

Comment: No repro, Chrome 53.0.2785.116 on Linux Mint.

Comment: The menu behaves like you describe if the javascript isn't loaded or raised an error. Can you verify in the Developer Console that there are no errors, either from load or otherwise?

Comment: @rene: As I said, the menu works fine on SE meta. I don't know anything about the developer console.

Comment: @Gothdo: Did you also try reverting to the pre-Material style: "Chrome://flags/#top-chrome-md"?

Comment: @Drew Yes. Since you see the same thing in IE 11, it's probably a problem with your internet connection.

Comment: @Gothdo: My internet connection? How so? (I don't notice any problem with my internet connection.)

Comment: Can you load the site over `https://` instead of `http://`? Do you run a virus-scanner/ internet protection stuff? I know of at least one report where such tool interfered with network connections.

Comment: @Drew A firewall could be blocking some JavaScript files.

Comment: @rene: Yep! That's it, it seems. With https the problems go away. Does this mean that I need to change all my SE bookmarks etc. and start using https? Does it mean I need to switch back and forth, depending on whether I am within the company VPN? Or is this something that SE will/should fix? Thx.

Comment: @rene: Why would it be the case that things work fine on this meta SE site, but not on other SE sites?

Comment: @rene: FYI, I haven't changed anything at my end. I've been accessing SE sites for years from within the company firewall or VPN. Maybe they just changed something wrt the firewall, though; dunno.

Comment: No repro, Chrome 53.0.2785.116 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @Drew virusscanners and network proxies (specially in corporate environments) are known to update regularly. It could well be that either on your PC or a network engineers applied a patch / virus definition that considers some content coming from SE or Google or a CDN as untrusted. You can ask to whitelist the domains needed or configure that in your virus software.

Comment: You can find a list of domains that need to be white-listed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100), including the main sites you visit off course .

Comment: @rene: I don't see any way to white-list domains in my anti-virus client (McAfee). I'm not sure I even have that possibility. Guess I'll have to change my bookmarks from http to https...

Comment: @rene: I've done that now (changed bookmarks to be https). Thanks for the help, everyone. Let me know whether I should delete this question. Thx.

Comment: Thanks @Drew for reporting back. I think it is fine to keep the question in case other run into the same problem. So the regulars here can keep track how often this happens.

Comment: @rene: Actually, the solution of entering via https does not really work. As soon as I try to add a comment or look at hidden comments or go to another SE site via the Stack Exchange dropdown, everything is broken again. All of those links and dropdown-menu addresses are http, not https. Is there some way to tell SE to always use https instead of http? Without that I'm afraid I really won't be able to use SE anymore - not for much, anyway.

Comment: @rene: I guess the problem is only wrt stuff that shows up in the black bar as a comment flag or points flag. Visiting those seems to be always with http, not https.

Comment: @Drew the problem is that https is not yet fully supported, see [these search results](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=%20http%20https%20ssl), however, what you describe seems to be [protocol relative issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223725/all-internal-links-on-stack-exchange-sites-should-be-protocol-relative) which has a sort-of-fix in [SOUP](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224875/158100).

Comment: @rene: Thanks for that info. FWIW, I think (so far), and hope, that what I saw was due to having visited those pages using http. E.g, if a user added a comment then the dropdown for the flags linked to the http address for that comment. Your comment today, for instance, was linked to correctly from a flag dropdown, as https. So I'm hoping that this problem will gradually disappear, as I visit pages only using https.

Comment: @rene: Nope, I was wrong in my last supposition. I just got a comment addressed to me on a page that I had visited only using https. And when I followed the dropdown comment note to that page I was unable to upvote, add a comment, etc. The page was visited as http only (even though I came from an https SE page and was taken to an SE page that I previously visited using only https).