# Fix http://data.stackexchange.com to https://data.stackexchange.com with Community♦ for correct session handling

Tags: support, data-explorer, community-user, ssl

If I click on an HTTPS link to https://data.stackexchange.com, I will be identified:

[image]

But if I click on an HTTP link to http://data.stackexchange.com, I will not be identified:

[image]

This HTTP issue prevents me from:

- Adding queries to my favorites
- Accessing my profile and my favorites
- Logging in (it will always fail when on HTTP)

As such, I would like the [Community ♦ bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) to perform the same job as it did for:

> replaced http://stackoverflow.com/ with https://stackoverflow.com/ 
> replaced http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ with https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

But this time for:

> replaced https://data.stackexchange.com/ with https://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: also, to consider: migrating some old links from **odata**.stackexchange.com to **data**.stackexchange.com (this requires to be careful, as it's not simply a one letter change, the path is often different as well). I have manually dealt with **odata** links on StackOverflow, but there are many left on StackExchange.

Comment: So **irrelevant** but are those all google chrome tabs ? how much is your ram ?

Comment: @atayenel MacBook Pro 2017, 16 GB, macOS Sierra, Chrome 60.

Comment: FWIW, my [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script provides a workaround for this problem as part of [this general fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224875).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen well noted, but [https everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) will fix it for.. everywhere on internet