# HTTPS opt-in during phase in

Tags: feature-request, ssl

When Facebook and Gmail were rolling out HTTPS support, there was an option to opt-in to use HTTPS. Is it possible to have a similar functionality for Stack Exchange sites?

I've read the blog post from [Roadmap for HTTPS/SSL support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226030/227404) and I suppose that implementation can be done either of these ways:

1. Allow users to opt-in for all sites
2. Allow users to opt-in for sites that are "pretty much HTTPS ready".

Having this as a checkbox on the preferences page of each site would be ideal.

Since HTTPS support isn't complete yet, I don't expect Stack Exchange to be sending HSTS headers and certainly do not expect the HTTP version to automatically redirect to HTTPS.

I'd like to use the site in HTTPS whenever possible and although I can add an "s" in the URL upon typing it the address bar, half the time I arrive onto an SE site via a Google search, which comes to the HTTP version.

Comment: So opt-in to SSL can be done using tools like [HTTPS Everywhere](https://eff.org/https-everywhere) as mentioned in [Steven V's answer](#236620), and this has the advantage of enabling HTTPS on more sites than just Stack Exchange. So I have requested a related feature that really gets to the issue that needs addressing as soon as possible (i.e. before complete rollout): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245115/opt-out-of-being-logged-in-without-ssl

Answer (score 2):

The difference is Facebook and Google officially supported HTTPS when they implemented the check box, and encouraged users to use it. Stack Exchange is still working through technical issues like meta.*.stackexchange.com having invalid certificates, and images still pointing to HTTP. Until HTTPS is officially supported, with zero certificate warnings and mixed content warnings, an official option to direct layman to HTTPS shouldn't be there.

I know browser extensions like HTTPS Everywhere do send people to the secured version of Stack Exchange sites. So if you want that functionality today, may want to try out a browser extension.

<sup>[Also the devs have said, once HTTPS is supported and turned on, HSTS headers will be used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223555/215013)</sup>

Comment: I'd say that HSTS is a *permanent* opt-in, so not really an opt-in. (I don't know if browsers clear that info when one clears their cache?)