# Election candidate cards use broken HTTPS meta links

Tags: bug, status-norepro, election, ssl

On election pages, such as [Software Recommendations' ongoing election](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election), if you're viewing the page over HTTPS, the candidate cards use HTTPS links.

Fine, that's pretty standard behaviour. The problem here is the "meta posts" link:

[image]

Meta HTTPS is broken (no wildcards in the middle of SSL certs) - so this link goes to a big red security warning page.

Comment: Related: [Broken links to per-site metas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270074/broken-links-to-per-site-metas)

Comment: Could you please change the embedded image to use HTTPS? Thanks.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara Can't actually tell if you're being sarcastic or not, but if not: I recommend having a browser extension that converts to HTTPS where possible. Then people who want HTTP can have it, and you can have HTTPS.

Comment: It’s not sarcasm, and extensions that convert to HTTPS where possible – at least the ones I use – don’t automatically rewrite mixed embedded content. The browser just blocks it. (So I don’t see an image when looking at your post, regardless of HTTPS Everywhere, because `security.mixed_content.block_display_content` is `true` – *as it should be*.) I *would* recommend a protocol-relative URI, but that breaks the mobile app, or at least it did at one point.

Comment: The HTML contains absolute link to the `http://` version. If you're running extension that change links to `https://` that's not SE problem and not a bug.

Answer (score 3):

<s>The only way to fix that (short of rearranging how meta site URLs are set up, which is planned, but keeps getting pushed back by more pressing things) is to force the link to go to HTTP only... which isn't great.</s>

We do not officially support HTTPS on our sites, even though most of the time it will work. Browsing through HTTPS is a choice at this point, so quietly forcing you back to plain HTTP feels worse than forcing you to make the informed "do I want to continue or do I want to bail?" decision. So if you're running that way *anyway*, clicking past that warning is probably gonna just have to be the price you pay for the time being.

Hold on a sec, I took a closer look at the code, and it looks like we're already linking to the plain HTTP version (gonna need to fix that one up once we go to full SSL support for sure). Are you running HTTPS Everywhere or a similar addon that forces all connections to go over HTTPS? Everything I said above still stands in the general case for the links that are already protocol-relative, but now that I've looked at the code, I don't see how we're creating what you're seeing.

Comment: You can't actually "click past the warning" because CloudFlare doesn't allow its connection and will just return a 403 Forbidden error if you add a security exception for your browser. But I agree forcing a http-only link is a bad idea.

Comment: @animuson Woof. That is even worse. However, I can't repro these particular links being HTTPS, so this may be moot anyway. Not a fan of leaving them HTTP-only given my own argument against that, but fixing that would actually mean *breaking* what should currently at least sort of work and I'm not into that either. :/ No graceful way out of this one short of proper HTTPS support... fingers crossed for 2016?

Comment: So, this looks like [tag:status-already-done].

Comment: If the OP was using [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup), that could've also caused this issue. I just pushed a fix for this as part of SOUP v1.42. Of course, the *real* problem is still that [per-site metas are broken over HTTPS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265918/accessing-per-site-metas-gives-403-forbidden-from-cloudflare-nginx).