# stackexchange.com (Calomel addon): security broken or untrusted (0%)

Tags: bug, ssl

I have the [Calomel addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/calomel-ssl-validation/) installed in Firefox, which evaluates the strength and quality of an SSL certificate when visiting an HTTPS site.

When visiting https://stackexchange.com/ it rates the certificate at 0% and says the security is broken, while at the same time all items score 100/100. On the meta the rating is 100%. Magento is broken, Askubuntu and Superuser are 100%, etc...

Is this a problem with the certificate, or is it a problem with the Calomel service?

Comment: Things like favorite icons are still loaded from unsecure location (e.g. http://cdn.sstatic.net/scifi/img/favicon.ico) that's why it's "broken".

Comment: As Nick says in the [linked dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216037/152859): *Don't use HTTPS, we don't fully support it yet... We intentionally don't link you to HTTPS anywhere that doesn't support it yet... if your browser extensions do so, they need adjusting*

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!